# Setting up SendGrid in Django

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I'm not able to send emails through Django using SendGrid.

I have configured my SendGrid account and created an API key and configured my Django settings files. Various online tutorials show different methods. None have worked for me. Here are my specific questions:

1. specific question is whether or not I need to pip install sendgrid.
2. specific question is should I be able to successfully test sending emails by going into the python shell and entering...

```
>> from django.core.mail import send_mail

>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

The above results in a "1" in the python shell output, but no email delivered.

3. Should the SendGrid dashboard show a new "Request" when the message is sent successfully? Mine shows 1 and has not changed.

Here is my Django `settings.py` file:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = get_env_variable('SEND_GRID_API_KEY')

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = SENDGRID_API_KEY
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: (1) No, you don't need to install anything; emails are sent via SMTP protocol and django has built in support for that. (2) Yes, you can send emails from a console. Be sure to run the console using this command: `python manage.py shell`.

Comment: This all looks good.  If it is not working, check the api key is right.  I've found you can get an unwanted space at the end of a SnedGrid key if you copy/paste it

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I ended up using google smtp, which worked fine after setting an app password since I have 2 factor auth. Will re-post if I get SendGrid working.